# Lucene/AzureSearch closest matches

Tags: search, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

A client is asking a feature that I'm not really sure how to develop.

The task is this: how to find the closest matches to a query and tell the missing terms in them. It's kind of what Google does when it doesn't find your exact query.

So the site have some services that have tags in them:
 - Tag1
 - Tag2
 - Tag3

Then we want to run a query that returns all the services with all the tags. So I can do something like a grouped AND. but let's say I want to also return the closest 5 services to what the user is looking for. For instance there can be services which only match Tag2 and Tag3.

I guess I could run a grouped OR query but the thing is how can I order them by the matched number of terms found?, is there any way I can create a custom scoring to do that? And how can I get those terms that are not in the results? (Tag1 in the example).

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you issue a simple query with all the tags, the documents that matched any of the tags will be returned an the ones that matched more of the tags will be promoted higher in the search result list.

```
search=Tag1 Tag2 Tag3
```

If you want to promote the documents that matched all of the tags even higher, you can use term boosting feature of [Lucene query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_termboost)

```
search=(Tag1 AND Tag2 AND Tag3)^3 OR Tag1 OR Tag2 OR Tag3&queryType=full
```

You can learn more about the defaul scoring function in Azure Search here: [How full text search works in Azure Search - scoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_termboost).

To see which terms matched you can use [hit highlighting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#highlightpretagstring-optional).

Comment: Thanks Yahnoosh. But the scoring I need is higher score to the results with higher number of matched terms, not only the ones that match them all. So a result that matches Tag1 and Tag2 will have same score than one with Tag2 and Tag3 but more than one that matches only Tag3.
Apart of that I need the inverse of the hit highlighting. I need to display those terms that are not in each of the partial results.

Comment: Then the default scoring behavior should be good enough for you. Have you tried it and it didn't meet your expectations? Once you know which terms matched you can determine which didn't. That's your best option.

Comment: Yes, it sounds right. I haven't tried the solution yet, but I have used Lucene before and I was confused about how to do this. I guess the default scoring will order the services by the number of matches. I'll have to extract the missing terms using the highlighted ones. Thanks.